# Angular route guard executed before user authentication

Tags: angular, angular-route-guards

I implemented a simple route guard that redirects to the login page if a user is not authenticated, where the check for login is of type `Observable`.

The guard is working as expected, but if the user is logged-in, navigates to a protected page:

```
{ path: 'protected-page', component: ProtectedComponent, canActivate: [authGuard] },
```

and reloads (ctrl+f5) the page, the user is redirected to the login page (because `BehaviorSubject` emits false by default). But if I switch to `Subject` the page is still loading and does not return.

I want the user is also redirected to the protected page again, if `userService` emits that this user is already logged-in. Or the route guard should wait till user-service emits the login status.

auth.guad.ts:

```
export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree => {
    const userService = inject( UserProfileService );
    const router = inject( Router );
      return userService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
        //take(1),
        map((loggedIn: boolean) => {
          if (loggedIn)
            return true;
          return router.createUrlTree(['/sign-in']);
        })
      );
  };
```

user-profile.service.ts

```
...
private loggedInSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
...
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean>{
  return this.loggedInSubject.asObservable();   
}
...
```

Comment: Maybe add a skip(1) helps to ignore the first emission?

Comment: Why does it need to be asynchronous at all? Why use an observable? Are you making some sort of api call during the routing process?

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in, try storing the authentication token in the browser's session storage. Then in the `isLoggedIn` function of `UserProfileService`, check if the auth token is in the session storage to tell if the user is logged in.

```
isLoggedIn(): boolean {
  const authToken = sessionStorage.getItem('AuthToken');
  return !!authToken;
}
```